# I am trying to get python to call a class every 5 seconds in pygame

Tags: python

I am trying to create a new obstacle class every five seconds

**Obstacle class I am trying to call**

```
class Obstacle(py.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,game,x,y):
        self.game = game
        self._layer = car_layer
        self.groups = self.game.all_sprites, self.game.Obstacle
        py.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.x = x * tilesize
        self.y = y * tilesize
        self.width = tilesize
        self.height = tilesize
        self.y_change = 0
        

        self.image = py.Surface([self.width,self.height])
        self.image.fill(green)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = self.x
        self.rect.y = self.y
    def update(self):
        self.movement()

        self.rect.y += self.y_change
        self.y_change = 0

    def movement(self):
            self.y_change += speed1
```

**I tried to use this to call it, but I just get obstacle is not callable**

```
Timer(5,Obstacle(self,j,i)).start()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "run the class"?  Do you have a set of Obstacle objects for which you want to run the `update` method every 5 seconds?  Do you want to create a new object every 5 seconds?

Comment: I would like to create a new object every 5 seconds, sorry shouldve clarified